# django - cannot import name settings

Tags: python, django

I'm working on a site in django that is actually in production. I'm trying to run it in local but i get the error: cannot import name settings when i try to access the main page.

This page use the bbcode apps that's correctly installed but that I suspect to be the source of my problem (pages without bbcode work well).

First, as asked here is the hierarchy of my project. Files with a ~ at the end are temporary files created by emacs, so don't pay attention to them. The correct settings.py is the one in /jdrpoly/, The other one was a test to see if it was helping

```
├── bbcode
│   ├── bbtags
│   │   ├── advanced.py
│   │   ├── advanced.pyc
│   │   ├── brainfuck.py
│   │   ├── brainfuck.pyc
│   │   ├── functional.py
│   │   ├── functional.pyc
│   │   ├── __init__.py
│   │   ├── __init__.pyc
│   │   ├── lists.py
│   │   ├── lists.pyc
│   │   ├── smilies.py
│   │   ├── smilies.pyc
│   │   ├── table.py
│   │   ├── table.pyc
│   │   ├── text_formatting.py
│   │   ├── text_formatting.pyc
│   │   └── web.py
│   ├── cli.py
│   ├── fields.py
│   ├── __init__.py
│   ├── __init__.pyc
│   ├── mypygments.py
│   ├── templates
│   │   └── bbcode
│   │       ├── bbhelp.html
│   │       └── bbtag.html
│   ├── templatetags
│   │   ├── bbcode.py
│   │   ├── bbcode.pyc
│   │   ├── __init__.py
│   │   └── __init__.pyc
│   └── views.py
├── events
│   ├── admin.py
│   ├── admin.pyc
│   ├── forms.py
│   ├── forms.pyc
│   ├── __init__.py
│   ├── __init__.pyc
│   ├── migrations
│   │   ├── 0001_initial.py
│   │   ├── 0001_initial.pyc
│   │   ├── __init__.py
│   │   └── __init__.pyc
│   ├── models.py
│   ├── models.pyc
│   ├── tests.py
│   ├── tests.pyc
│   ├── urls.py
│   ├── urls.pyc
│   ├── views.py
│   └── views.pyc
├── jdrpoly
│   ├── __init__.py
│   ├── __init__.pyc
│   ├── settings~
│   ├── settings.py
│   ├── settings.py~
│   ├── settings.pyc
│   ├── urls.py
│   ├── urls.pyc
│   ├── utils
│   │   └── text.py
│   ├── utils.py
│   ├── utils.pyc
│   ├── wsgi.py
│   └── wsgi.pyc
├── LICENSE
├── main
│   ├── admin.py
│   ├── admin.pyc
│   ├── __init__.py
│   ├── __init__.pyc
│   ├── migrations
│   │   ├── 0003_contest.py
│   │   ├── 0003_contest.py~
│   │   ├── 0003_contest.pyc
│   │   ├── 0004_comitymember_mainpagesection_news.py
│   │   ├── 0004_comitymember_mainpagesection_news.pyc
│   │   ├── __init__.py
│   │   └── __init__.pyc
│   ├── models.py
│   ├── models.pyc
│   ├── tests.py
│   ├── tests.pyc
│   ├── urls.py
│   ├── urls.pyc
│   ├── views.py
│   └── views.pyc
├── manage.py
├── members
│   ├── admin.py
│   ├── admin.pyc
│   ├── forms.py
│   ├── forms.pyc
│   ├── __init__.py
│   ├── __init__.pyc
│   ├── migrations
│   │   ├── 0001_initial.py
│   │   ├── 0001_initial.pyc
│   │   ├── 0002_code_member.py
│   │   ├── 0002_code_member.py~
│   │   ├── 0002_code_member.pyc
│   │   ├── 0003_member.py
│   │   ├── 0003_member.pyc
│   │   ├── __init__.py
│   │   └── __init__.pyc
│   ├── models.py
│   ├── models.pyc
│   ├── templates
│   │   ├── base.html
│   │   ├── comity.html
│   │   ├── concours.djhtml
│   │   ├── contact.html
│   │   ├── contact_success.html
│   │   ├── events
│   │   │   ├── attending.djhtml
│   │   │   ├── campaign_delete.djhtml
│   │   │   ├── campaign_detail.djhtml
│   │   │   ├── campaign_list.djhtml
│   │   │   ├── create.djhtml
│   │   │   ├── edition_view.djhtml
│   │   │   ├── list.djhtml
│   │   │   ├── menu_event.djhtml
│   │   │   ├── new_campaign.djhtml
│   │   │   ├── propose.djhtml
│   │   │   └── view.djhtml
│   │   ├── gallery
│   │   │   ├── list.html
│   │   │   └── view.html
│   │   ├── mainpage.html
│   │   ├── members
│   │   │   ├── code.html
│   │   │   ├── code_mail.txt
│   │   │   ├── code_use.html
│   │   │   ├── create.html
│   │   │   ├── edit.html
│   │   │   ├── main.html
│   │   │   ├── password_change.html
│   │   │   ├── password_change_ok.html
│   │   │   ├── password_reset.html
│   │   │   └── view.html
│   │   ├── news
│   │   │   ├── letter.html
│   │   │   ├── letter_ok.html
│   │   │   └── view.html
│   │   ├── registration
│   │   │   └── login.html
│   │   └── svz
│   │       ├── admin.html
│   │       ├── generic.html
│   │       └── index.html
│   ├── tests.py
│   ├── tests.pyc
│   ├── urls.py
│   ├── urls.pyc
│   ├── views.py
│   └── views.pyc
├── pictures
│   ├── admin.py
│   ├── admin.pyc
│   ├── __init__.py
│   ├── __init__.pyc
│   ├── migrations
│   │   ├── 0001_initial.py
│   │   ├── 0001_initial.pyc
│   │   ├── 0002_auto_20150831_1452.py
│   │   ├── 0002_auto_20150831_1452.pyc
│   │   ├── 0003_auto_20161213_2212.py
│   │   ├── 0003_auto_20161213_2212.pyc
│   │   ├── __init__.py
│   │   └── __init__.pyc
│   ├── models.py
│   ├── models.pyc
│   ├── tests.py
│   ├── tests.pyc
│   ├── urls.py
│   ├── urls.pyc
│   ├── views.py
│   └── views.pyc
├── settings.py
├── static
│   ├── assets
│   │   ├── css
│   │   │   ├── font-awesome.min.css
│   │   │   ├── ie8.css
│   │   │   ├── images
│   │   │   │   └── bracket.svg
│   │   │   └── main.css
│   │   ├── fonts
│   │   │   ├── FontAwesome.otf
│   │   │   ├── fontawesome-webfont.eot
│   │   │   ├── fontawesome-webfont.svg
│   │   │   ├── fontawesome-webfont.ttf
│   │   │   ├── fontawesome-webfont.woff
│   │   │   └── fontawesome-webfont.woff2
│   │   ├── js
│   │   │   ├── ie
│   │   │   │   ├── backgroundsize.min.htc
│   │   │   │   ├── html5shiv.js
│   │   │   │   ├── PIE.htc
│   │   │   │   └── respond.min.js
│   │   │   ├── jquery.dropotron.min.js
│   │   │   ├── jquery.min.js
│   │   │   ├── main.js
│   │   │   ├── skel.min.js
│   │   │   ├── skel-viewport.min.js
│   │   │   └── util.js
│   │   └── sass
│   │       ├── ie8.scss
│   │       ├── libs
│   │       │   ├── _functions.scss
│   │       │   ├── _mixins.scss
│   │       │   ├── _skel.scss
│   │       │   └── _vars.scss
│   │       └── main.scss
│   ├── images
│   │   ├── banner.jpg
│   │   ├── banner.png
│   │   ├── default.jpg
│   │   ├── no-image.png
│   │   ├── pic01.jpg
│   │   ├── pic02.jpg
│   │   ├── pic03.jpg
│   │   ├── pic04.jpg
│   │   ├── pic05.jpg
│   │   ├── pic06.jpg
│   │   └── pic07.jpg
│   └── svz
│       ├── assets
│       │   ├── css
│       │   │   ├── font-awesome.min.css
│       │   │   ├── ie8.css
│       │   │   ├── ie9.css
│       │   │   ├── images
│       │   │   │   └── intro.svg
│       │   │   └── main.css
│       │   ├── fonts
│       │   │   ├── FontAwesome.otf
│       │   │   ├── fontawesome-webfont.eot
│       │   │   ├── fontawesome-webfont.svg
│       │   │   ├── fontawesome-webfont.ttf
│       │   │   ├── fontawesome-webfont.woff
│       │   │   └── fontawesome-webfont.woff2
│       │   ├── js
│       │   │   ├── admin.js
│       │   │   ├── ie
│       │   │   │   ├── html5shiv.js
│       │   │   │   └── respond.min.js
│       │   │   ├── jquery.min.js
│       │   │   ├── jquery.scrollex.min.js
│       │   │   ├── jquery.scrolly.min.js
│       │   │   ├── main.js
│       │   │   ├── skel.min.js
│       │   │   └── util.js
│       │   └── sass
│       │       ├── base
│       │       │   ├── _page.scss
│       │       │   └── _typography.scss
│       │       ├── components
│       │       │   ├── _box.scss
│       │       │   ├── _button.scss
│       │       │   ├── _features.scss
│       │       │   ├── _form.scss
│       │       │   ├── _icon.scss
│       │       │   ├── _image.scss
│       │       │   ├── _list.scss
│       │       │   ├── _section.scss
│       │       │   ├── _split.scss
│       │       │   ├── _spotlights.scss
│       │       │   ├── _table.scss
│       │       │   └── _wrapper.scss
│       │       ├── ie8.scss
│       │       ├── ie9.scss
│       │       ├── layout
│       │       │   ├── _footer.scss
│       │       │   ├── _header.scss
│       │       │   ├── _intro.scss
│       │       │   ├── _sidebar.scss
│       │       │   └── _wrapper.scss
│       │       ├── libs
│       │       │   ├── _functions.scss
│       │       │   ├── _mixins.scss
│       │       │   ├── _skel.scss
│       │       │   └── _vars.scss
│       │       └── main.scss
│       └── images
│           ├── pic01.jpg
│           ├── pic02.jpg
│           ├── pic03.jpg
│           ├── pic04.jpg
│           ├── pic05.jpg
│           └── pic06.jpg
└── svz
    ├── admin.py
    ├── admin.pyc
    ├── apps.py
    ├── __init__.py
    ├── __init__.pyc
    ├── migrations
    │   ├── 0001_initial.py
    │   ├── 0001_initial.pyc
    │   ├── 0002_auto_20161213_2212.py
    │   ├── 0002_auto_20161213_2212.pyc
    │   ├── 0003_auto_20170209_1516.py
    │   ├── 0003_auto_20170209_1516.pyc
    │   ├── 0004_auto_20170209_1612.py
    │   ├── 0004_auto_20170209_1612.pyc
    │   ├── 0005_auto_20170209_1621.py
    │   ├── 0005_auto_20170209_1621.pyc
    │   ├── 0006_auto_20170224_1248.py
    │   ├── 0006_auto_20170224_1248.pyc
    │   ├── 0007_player_faction.py
    │   ├── 0007_player_faction.pyc
    │   ├── 0008_auto_20170313_1033.py
    │   ├── 0008_auto_20170313_1033.pyc
    │   ├── __init__.py
    │   └── __init__.pyc
    ├── models.py
    ├── models.pyc
    ├── templates
    │   └── svz
    │       └── concours_affiche.html
    ├── tests.py
    ├── tests.pyc
    ├── urls.py
    ├── urls.pyc
    ├── views.py
    └── views.pyc
```

When i run `manage.py runserver` everything goes well

Then here is the StackTrace when i'm trying to access the main page:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib64/python2.7/wsgiref/handlers.py", line 85, in run
    self.result = application(self.environ, self.start_response)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/contrib/staticfiles/handlers.py", line 63, in __call__
    return self.application(environ, start_response)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/handlers/wsgi.py", line 170, in __call__
    response = self.get_response(request)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py", line 124, in get_response
    response = self._middleware_chain(request)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/handlers/exception.py", line 44, in inner
    response = response_for_exception(request, exc)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/handlers/exception.py", line 94, in response_for_exception
    response = handle_uncaught_exception(request, get_resolver(get_urlconf()), sys.exc_info())
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/handlers/exception.py", line 42, in inner
    response = get_response(request)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py", line 249, in _legacy_get_response
    response = self._get_response(request)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py", line 217, in _get_response
    response = self.process_exception_by_middleware(e, request)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py", line 215, in _get_response
    response = response.render()
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/template/response.py", line 109, in render
    self.content = self.rendered_content
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/template/response.py", line 84, in rendered_content
    template = self.resolve_template(self.template_name)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/template/response.py", line 66, in resolve_template
    return select_template(template, using=self.using)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/template/loader.py", line 48, in select_template
    return engine.get_template(template_name)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/template/backends/django.py", line 39, in get_template
    return Template(self.engine.get_template(template_name), self)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/template/engine.py", line 160, in get_template
    template, origin = self.find_template(template_name)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/template/engine.py", line 134, in find_template
    name, template_dirs=dirs, skip=skip,
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/template/loaders/base.py", line 44, in get_template
    contents, origin, origin.template_name, self.engine,
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/template/base.py", line 191, in __init__
    self.nodelist = self.compile_nodelist()
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/template/base.py", line 233, in compile_nodelist
    return parser.parse()
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/template/base.py", line 518, in parse
    raise self.error(token, e)
ImportError: cannot import name settings
[02/Nov/2017 19:10:31] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 500 59
```

I checked all the imports and they are correct, tried to specify the settings directly when running manage.py with `--settings=...`, tried also to specify the PYTHONPATH.

I've run out of ideas.

One last thing, this website, with exactly the same files is currently running on a server and do not have any problems of this kind.

Comment: Can you share the directory hierarchy, possibly you are missing __init__.py file.

Comment: hierarchy added, and normally all init.py are present

Comment: Which settings file is correct? `website/settings.py` or `website/jdrpoly/settings.py`? And what is `website/jdrpoly/settings~` ?

Comment: the both are the same, the one in /jdrpoly/settings is the correct one, the other was a test to see if it was helping. The files with a ~ are temp files created by emacs

Comment: The error is reraised in django's template rendering engine. Since you are not using python3, the stacktrace does not show the original error. But my guess it that some custom template tag has a bug. Use a debugger to trace the error to the correct file. Or use grep to search for `import .* settings` in the bbcode directory. You might find the error that way.

Comment: PS: I highly recommend upgrading your python version. With python 3, the traceback would have contained the original stack trace as well. And the upcoming django 2.0 is not compatible with python2.7

Comment: I foud the error, it was effectively an import that was false in the bbcode/bbtags folder. Thank's a lot for your answer and your time!  PS: I would like to upgrade to python 3 but the bbcode apps is for now only available in python2. But it is on my plan ;).

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

from django.conf import settings